# exception with clicking button

Tags: android, exception

what does this exception means ? 
it just give a message unfortunately your app has stopped .

```
      05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735): Process:   com.example.hospitalsdirectorysystem, PID: 735
   05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):  at com.example.hospitalsdirectorysystem.MorningDrsGeneral$1.onClick(MorningDrsGeneral.java:72)
    05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
    05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19839)
   05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
  05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
  05-11 01:52:18.189: E/AndroidRuntime(735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

and here is my .java code 
public void addListenerOnButton1() {

```
        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


            if (rb0.isChecked())
            {


                texx = "you choose Dr.Kamal , he is available at 8:30 - 9:00     ";
           textView7.setText(texx);


            }


                }



        });}
```

and note that i put this segment of code in the global :

```
      RadioButton rb0 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
```

and this where i define textView7

```
  public class MorningDrsGeneral extends ActionBarActivity {
```

String texx ;

TextView textView7 ;

RadioButton rb0  ;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.morningdrs);

     rb0 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    addListenerOnButton1();
  }
  public void addListenerOnButton1() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: Where do you define the textView7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you haven't found and initiated the TextView before running this code. You need to have this before button.setOnClickListener:

```
textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.THE ID OF YOUR TEXT VIEW);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although you say there is a TextView, you never associate it with your layout.  What you need to do is associate the TextView with your layout by doing.

```
textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YourTextViewId);
```

Without this you get a NullPointerException because the textView7 is not set to anything and is therefore null.